# Android M request permission not working

Tags: android, permissions, request

Here is my code. Method requestPermission didn't working on Android M. **Please help me, thank you very much.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE},REQUEST_PERMISSION);

}
```

In my **AndroidManifest** file, I have already added **user-permission** tags. But it not showing permission dialog. My SdkVersion is 25.

Answer (score 0):

`INTERNET` is not one of [the `dangerous` permissions that requires `requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous). You do not need `requestPermissions()` to be able to use the `INTERNET` permission. Just have the `<uses-permission>` element in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The `INTERNET` permission does not require to request it in runtime.